# Deriving the properties of derivative operators

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tensor-products, general-relativity

> The difference in the action of $\bar{\triangledown_a}$ and $\triangledown_a$ on vector fields and all higher rank tensor fields is determined by
>
> $${\triangledown}_a \omega_b=\bar{\triangledown}_a\omega_b-C^c_{ab}\omega_c $$
>
> , the Liebnitz rule and
>
> 4) For all $f \in \mathfrak{F}$ and all $t^a \in V_p$
>
> $$t(f) = t^a\triangledown_a f$$
>
> and 4) tells us that
>
> $$(\bar{\bigtriangledown}_a - \bigtriangledown_a)\omega_bt^b=0$$

I am not sure how this last equality holds? I cannot even see how it is related?

This is from Wald's General Relativity, page 33.

Comment: $\omega _bt^b$ is a scalar, and the last identity is true for scalars (this follows from 4)). Liebnitz and this will give you the identity similar to the first one for $t^b$.

Comment: @MBN could you put that as an answer please?